# Get the root key with jsonb_path_query()

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath, json-path-expression

In Postgres 13, for the below query, the `jsonb` values are getting filtered correctly based on "priority":

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(
'{
  "100": {
    "name": "test",
    "priority": 5
  },
  "101": {
    "name": "test2",
    "priority": 10
  },
  "102": {
    "name": "test3",
    "priority": 15
  }                     
}'
, '$.* ? (@.priority > 10)')
```

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "test3",
  "priority": 15
}
```

But I want to get the root key also. In this case I want to get the root for "test3" which is "102". To achieve this, I tried the below query:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(
'{
  "100": {
    "name": "test",
    "priority": 5
  },
  "101": {
    "name": "test2",
    "priority": 10
  },
  "102": {
    "name": "test3",
    "priority": 15
  }                     
}'
, '$ ? (@.*.priority > 10)')
```

But the output data is not getting filtered based on "priority".
Here is the output:

```json
{
  "100": {
    "name": "test",
    "priority": 5
  },
  "101": {
    "name": "test2",
    "priority": 10
  },
  "102": {
    "name": "test3",
    "priority": 15
  }
}
```

The desired output would be:

```json
{
    "102": {
        "name": "test3",
        "priority": 15
    }
}
```

How can I filter the data using an SQL/JSON path expression and the get the root key as well?

Comment: I took the liberty to clarify. Correct the question if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task would be simple with a JSON ***array*** instead of a JSON object (which would seem like the more appropriate structure for your sample data):

```sql
SELECT jsonb_path_query(
'[
    {
        "100": {
            "name": "test",
            "priority": 5
        }
    },
    {
        "101": {
            "name": "test2",
            "priority": 10
        }
    },
    {
        "102": {
            "name": "test3",
            "priority": 15
        }
    }
]'
, '$[*] ? (@.*.priority > 10)');
```

While working with a JSON ***object***, one way would be with the [`.keyvalue()` method](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-OP-TABLE):

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(
'{
  "100": {
    "name": "test",
    "priority": 5
  },
  "101": {
    "name": "test2",
    "priority": 10
  },
  "102": {
    "name": "test3",
    "priority": 15
  }                     
}'
, '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value.priority > 10)');
```

Returns:

```json
{"id": 0, "key": "102", "value": {"name": "test3", "priority": 15}}
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-OP-TABLE)

> ***`object`*** `.` `keyvalue()` → ***`array`***
>
> The object's key-value pairs, represented as an array of objects
> containing three fields: `"key"`, `"value"`, and `"id"`; `"id"` is a
> unique identifier of the object the key-value pair belongs to

To get your desired JSON value exactly:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(j->>'key', j->'value')
FROM  (
   SELECT jsonb_path_query(
   '{
     "100": {
       "name": "test",
       "priority": 5
     },
     "101": {
       "name": "test2",
       "priority": 10
     },
     "102": {
       "name": "test3",
       "priority": 15
     }                     
   }'
   , '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value.priority > 10)') 
   ) sub(j);
```

Returns:

```json
{"102": {"name": "test3", "priority": 15}}
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c98fa789fbbde4b620f1aab919646a19)*